# IIS - All application pools stopped on a specific time

Tags: iis-10, windows-server-2019

I'm facing a weird behaviour from IIS where all the app pools configured in IIS has been stopped state exact time daily. No logs on event viewer or IIS.

Setup: 
We have 2 servers having OS "Windows server 2019" and IIS 10.0.  we hosted a service handlers on both the servers and it was working fine til last month. this service handler has separate app pool that has been created.

Issue: 
For last couple of weeks, we are facing an issue where all the app pools (default pool, handlers pool, classic 4.0) on the IIS stopped unexpectedly exactly at 3pm on server1 and 4pm on server2 on a daily basis.

Already tried:
1. Site running in "app pool identity"  and not custom. no password change required.
2.  No trace of event log in event viewer or iis
3.  Enabled Operational logging and no log while stopped.
4.  Made sure all the required dependencies installed on Windows features for IIS.

Any clues?

Comment: Did you get 503 error when you access these applications at that time? Besides, did you get any error in HTTPERR log? And did you notice all application pool get stopped due to inactivity in event viewer?

Comment: One way is to attach a debugger to one of the worker processes, and wait till the culprit to shut down the pool and kill the worker process. The debugger might help identify what happens then. If possible, open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com and work with Microsoft support team.